# Replacement of dump_stack() in freertos

Tags: gdb, freertos, backtrace

I have FreeRTOS running on ARM processor and I don't have dump_stack() available to me... I am trying to check the call-chain and badly missing dump_stack()... I was googling a bit, and found something close to what i was looking for, using GCC(/GDB) _Unwind_Backtrace() utility but it only prints the address of stack_frame. It doesn't provide mapping to meaningful symbol (like function names). Any help is really appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unwind.h>
#include <stdint.h>


static _Unwind_Reason_Code unwind_backtrace_callback(struct     _Unwind_Context* context, void* arg)
{

    uintptr_t pc = _Unwind_GetIP(context);
    if (pc) {
        printf("unwind got pc ...0x%x\n", pc);
    }

    return _URC_NO_REASON;
}

ssize_t unwind_backtrace()
{
    _Unwind_Reason_Code rc = _Unwind_Backtrace(unwind_backtrace_callback, 0);
    return rc == _URC_END_OF_STACK ? 0 : -1;
}

void func_1()
{
    int ret = unwind_backtrace();
    printf("unwind_backtrace return ...%d\n", ret);
}

void func_2()
{
   func_1();
}


int main()
{
    func_2();
    return 0;
}

Result:
unwind got pc ...0x40076b
unwind got pc ...0x400796
unwind got pc ...0x4007bd
unwind got pc ...0x400819
unwind got pc ...0x67314b15
unwind got pc ...0x400649
unwind_backtrace return ...0
```

Answer (score 0):

All the IDEs I use (and I use a lot) show me the stack trace in a window - but only for the currently executing task.  If I want to see the trace for all the tasks I need a fully thread aware FreeRTOS plug-in of the type provided by Segger, IAR and Code Confidence.

Comment: Hi Richard, Thanks for responding. Actually I am kind of using Linux-Cscope-Ctags combo to write/browse the firmware code and cross-compile against the GCC/ARM chain. Now loaded the binary in device (I don't have JTAG device) and want to check the call-chainin some function.

Answer (score 0):

> It doesn't provide mapping to meaningful symbol

The "standard" way to perform this mapping is by using [addr2line](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/addr2line.1.html). Something like:

```
addr2line -fe a.out 0x40076b 0x400796 0x4007bd ...
```

**Update:**

> I want on the fly convert ...

Well, you should have asked for *that* then.

It's a simple matter of writing code. You need to write code that will map address ranges to symbol names (just like `addr2line` does).

On an ELF platform, this is actually quite simple: read `Elf32_Sym`s from `.symtab` section to build address to symbol map, and look up your addresses in that map. You'll also need to read corresponding symbol *names* from `.strtab` section (`Elf32_Sym.st_name` is the offset into `.strtab`).

Comment: thanks for "addr2line" suggestion. This is to convert HEX symbols to FUNCTION name offline. I want on the fly convert....